# how to create a cronJob run every 0.25 hour

Tags: linux, unix, cron

How do I want to create a cron job on Linux that runs every 0.25 hour?

Answer (score 15):

As well as rslite's

```
0,15,30,45 * * * *  command-to-be-executed
```

This should work on most versions of cron

```
*/15 * * * * command-to-be-executed
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this to the crontab file:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * *  command-to-be-executed
```

Answer (score 3):

```
*/15 * * * * some-command
```

Comment: Don't forget to specify full path for `some-command`. E.g. not `perl` but `/usr/bin/perl`.

Answer (score 3):

`14,29,44,59 * * * * full-path-of-command-to-execute with argument`

Just to avoid the rush at XX:00

:-)

Comment: Oh, I like this.

Answer (score 1):

Set minutes as `0,15,30,45` or starting from any other minute of hour.